# Draw right brace which covers first four items of enumerated list

Tags: braces

Question:

How can i draw `big right brace` which is covering first four items?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[left=1.500cm, right=1.500cm, top=1.500cm, bottom=1.500cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \Large
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries(1),left=0pt]
    \item First
    \item Second
    \item Third
    \item Fourth
    \item Fifth
    \item Sixth
    \item Seventh
    \item Eighth
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tikzmark` and `calligraphic brace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,
                tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries(1),left=0pt]
    \item \tikzmarknode{A}{First}
    \item Second
    \item Third
    \item \tikzmarknode{B}{Fourth}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,
                          BC/.style = {decorate,
                                decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=5pt,
                                raise=0.5em, #1}, % for mirroring of brace
                                very thick,pen colour=red} % <---
                        ]
        \draw[BC={}] (A.north -| B.east) -- node[right=1em] {some remark(s)} (B.south east); % <---
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \item Fifth
    \item Sixth
    \item Seventh
    \item Eighth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** 
to brace you can ad some text (remark) with node in brace draw command:

```
        \draw[BC={}] (A.north -| B.east) -- node[right=1em] {some remark(s)} (B.south east);
```

[image]

Comment: Again a beautiful answer from you...

Comment: @MadyYuvi, also your is very interesting! (+1)

Comment: @Zarko also thanks to you for wonderful reply.

Comment: @Zarko I would like to ask one more question. Can I write some text to right side of this brace? Please reply me.

Comment: @Maths4Sandy, yes you can. I will edit my answer asap

Comment: Thanking you in advance. I am waiting.

Comment: i am looking for exactly what in your entered image.

Comment: Exactly where I have to add some comment, I don't know please help me...

Comment: @Maths4Sandy, ups, i upload old version of code, Sorry for any inconvenience which I made with this. Now this is corrected.

Answer (score 3):

Hope the below tags may helps you to meet the requirement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep,start=1]
    \item First      \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate (A) at (0pt,.6\baselineskip);}
    \item Second
    \item Third
    \item Fourth
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,decoration=brace]
        \coordinate (B) at (0pt,-.3\baselineskip);
        \coordinate (AB) at (A-|B);% when A left of B
        \draw[decorate,thick] (AB) -- (B);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \item Fifth
    \item Sixth
    \item Seventh
    \item Eighth
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.